# Rebel Assault II issues with PS3

Tags: ps3, backwards-compatibility, star-wars-rebel-assault-2

The menus work fine but any FMV flickers really bad with only the left 1/4 of the screen actually viewable. The disc is a bit scratched but not severe. Is this a compatibility issue or could scratches cause this? The sound is fine as well.

Comment: Looks like it has more to do with emulation. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh1ERrmW-gA Still would be nice to find a fix though.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a fix, but I confirmed that the game works fine in a PS2. Looks like there isn't much that can be done.